# Deserialization json into an object in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

OK SO I Am using http party to allow me get details back form a json example I am using stack overflow as my example as per a previous so question here.

My Question how  would i normally Deserialization this into a object that would be allowed to be used in my view so i created a controller called fetchjson.rb my question is how do i link that up to my view and also how do I get a model that is valid for rials 5

```
require 'httparty'
# Use the class methods to get down to business quickly
response = HTTParty.get('http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?site=stackoverflow')

puts response.body, response.code, response.message, response.headers.inspect

# Or wrap things up in your own class
class StackExchange
  include HTTParty
  base_uri 'api.stackexchange.com'

  def initialize(service, page)
    @options = { query: { site: service, page: page } }
  end

  def questions
    self.class.get("/2.2/questions", @options)
  end

  def users
    self.class.get("/2.2/users", @options)
  end
end

stack_exchange = StackExchange.new("stackoverflow", 1)
puts stack_exchange.questions
puts stack_exchange.users
```

I see here it has placed it into the object properties but how would i then pass that to my view for consumption in the page.

I am using this an example in my real wold I am using fields like long and latitude and dropping pins on a map. I have the map up already from  I just need to no how to access the stack exchange object on the view.

Comment: Such a confusing question, talking about C# then Rails. Talking about Stack Overflow then dropping lat/lon pins. Make your mind up and ask the question you want to ask. Keep it simple

Comment: @jamesc I am c# programmer comming from c# to ruby i am just learning

Comment: @jamesc I have removed my c# question the community needs to be open to programmes from other languages the where around allot longer than ruby.

Comment: The community has tags for just about every technology. Your question was incredibly difficult to decipher, tagged for Rails and totally confusing. Nothing to do with open mindedness, just distinct lack of clarity. Hoping you would clear it up in order to get the best answer for you I pointed this out. No offence was meant. As a Programmer that has been around a lot longer than C#, I am fully aware of other other languages. I cut my teeth on BBC Basic, Assembler, machine code and COBOL. Good luck with your search for help on this subject

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and most straightforward way of exposing data from your controller to the view just like you would any other object: an instance variable.

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    stack_exchange = StackExchange.new("stackoverflow", 1)
    @questions = stack_exchange.questions
  end 
end
```

`HTTParty` has a method called `parsed_response` you can call and it will try to parse the response based on received headers — if it's XML, it'll try to parse it as XML. If it's json, it'll try to parse it as JSON. Then, you're given an object to work with: presumably a JSON-ish (array or hash) object. If you need to see the response yourself, just call `@questions.response.body` — or dig around what methods are available `@questions.methods`.

We can fiddle around with this by hitting `@questions.parsed_response.class` and it'll probably return Hash or Array (probably of hashes). Assuming it's a hash, you can do `@questions.parsed_response.keys` to get the keys you can use to access the  values. If it's an array (again, probably of hashes), `@questions.parsed_response.first.keys`